# how to trigger button to open up user input/text box

Tags: javascript, html, css

so im trying to create "kanban/to do list" website, and im having trouble with triggering the add button. Im trying to trigger "add" button to open up a user input box. So I have this "add" button which creates a small box. but i cannot figure out how to add a small area in that box where i could write any type of text.

Ive done alot of reasearch, but no one is making the same type of to do list app.

```
div class="board">
    <div class="board-column todo">
            <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="addEvent()">+</button>
            <div class="board-column-header">To do</div>
            <div class="board-column-content"></div>


.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:25px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    background: #4A9FF9;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.2);
    font-size:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
```

forgot to mention. in this spesific box, i want to have that input/text box

```
    board-item-content {
        position: relative;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.2);
    }
```

Comment: Show where you define ```addEvent()```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do something like that using jquery / javascript**

Note : this is small idea example, you can change as per your need.

```js
function addEvent() {
var html = "<input type='text' name='box'>";
$('.board-column-content').append(html);

}
```

```css
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:25px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    background: #4A9FF9;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.2);
    font-size:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="board-column todo">
            <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="addEvent()">+</button>
            <div class="board-column-header">To do</div>
            <div class="board-column-content"></div>
```

Comment: No need for jquery, just use
document.querySelectorAll('.board-column-content')[0].innerHTML = html;

Comment: ya right, thats why i noted that this is just demo for idea.

Comment: I understand, but since there's no jquery in the question tags I think it's better to stick to vanilla js.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addEvent() {
  var txt;
  var task1 = prompt("Please enter your task:", "Task Name");
  if (task1 == null || task1 == "") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
  } else {
    txt = "You have added : " + task1 + "as a task!";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

````css
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:25px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    background: #4A9FF9;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.2);
    font-size:20px;
    cursor: pointer;```
````

```html
   <div class="board-column todo">
            <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="addEvent()">+</button>
            <div class="board-column-header">To do</div>
            <div class="board-column-content"></div>
            
            
            <p id="demo"></p>
```